# Swift Playgrounds Bookshelf Title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I recently downloaded the `Swift Playgrounds Xcode 10 Template` from the Apple website and following the guide everything works except of that I'm unable to set the books title inside the Swift Playgrounds Apps bookshelf. If I change the `Name` property inside the `Manifest.plist` it only changes the header of the table of contents. However I want to change the name shown before you even open the book.

Can someone guide me on how to do that? I didn't find any documentation explaining that.

EDIT: As it seems - it's not clear what I want. I'm trying to change the book title of a Swift Playgrounds Book see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_playgrounds

[image: Change the highlighted title]

Comment: please show us the code you're having an issue with, as it stands right now we have no idea how to help you

Comment: As you might know: Swift Playgrounds does not have any code. At least none for the Bookshelf. It's a project file with a special buildconfig. You can find the template I mentioned above here: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_playgrounds/creating_and_running_a_playground_book](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_playgrounds/creating_and_running_a_playground_book)

Comment: No, I had no idea

Comment: I know it's confusing, because of the naming similarity of Swift Playground and Swift Playgrounds. The "s" is important, because the one with the "s" is an app on iOS (iPad only) made by Apple where you can publish interactive books.

Answer (score 1):

I think your should do as the `README.md` suggests and change the following line in `BuildSettings.xcconfig`:

```
PLAYGROUND_BOOK_FILE_NAME = PlaygroundBook
```

Comment: I read the readme, but I thought this was the "FILE" name, not the title shown. However, one question stays. How do I localize this title?

Comment: I do not think you can. It is the filename after all. I just tried to download a book while the iPad was in English, changed localization to another one and the book title stayed the same. You can [localize the subscription feed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_playgrounds/localizing_a_subscription_feed?language=objc) though

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but one other thing I noticed was that micro:bit has the ":" in the book name. How to do that? After all it is a file name and the ":" will normally be removed.